# Java: Print multiple strings to a new command prompt window

Tags: java, command-prompt

I was wondering: how I can I take several strings, and output them to a command prompt window? For example say I had:

```
String a = "part";
String b = "number";
String c = "three";
```

And I wanted to print each of these strings to a **new** command prompt window. For example, I would run the program from Eclipse or IDEA, and it would open up a new command prompt window. How would I do this?

Comment: You want each string to appear on a different console from different IDEs? But that will never happen, which ever IDE you use, the output will be the same.

Comment: @user3437460 No, the goal is to be able to run the program, have it open a brand new Command Prompt window, and print out/"echo" the strings to the command prompt window.I believe I need to use something along the lines of 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec()', I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you would possibly want to do this, but generally you can call whatever command prompt program your operating system is running. For example on Windows:

"cmd.exe /k echo hello"

Will print out hello. So in java it would be something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k echo "+a);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k echo "+b);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k echo "+c);
```